# CakePHP tree behaviour not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am learning cakePHP 3 and trying to store hierarchical data in a table. I have added parent_id, lft and rght columns. Added $this->addBehavior('Tree') in initialize method for this table. Calling recover method.

So seems all is done as described here: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/tree.html
But no one child row is returned.

I am newbie in cakePHP, so maybe someone can help, what I am doing wrong?

That is interesting, that childCount returns -0.5 for each row (no matter if the row has children or not).

Comment: Sounds like your tree is broken... you'd have to add some more details (dump of your database table contents, code involved saving/reading tree data, etc) in order for people to be able to help you.

Comment: I noticed that recover method doesn't work. When I manually adding rght and lft all works fine. But I would like to make this method working, because table has too much rows (in case of manually adding)